# Detect tap on UIViewCollectionCell inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to detect a tap on imageview in uicollectionviewcell inside uitableviewcell

I'm using an api response to build a data in my tableview

I have this API response:

```
{"status":1,"data":{"blocks":[{"name":"CustomBlock","description":"CustomDescription","itemsType":"game","items":[510234,78188,15719,37630]}], "items":[{"id:"1", name: "testgame"}]}
```

BlocksViewController.swift

```
class BlocksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {
var blocks = [Block]() // I'm getting blocks in this controller
var items : BlockItem! // and items
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return blocks[collectionView.tag].items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GameCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? GameCollectionCell else { return
        UICollectionViewCell() }

    if let found = items.game.first(where: {$0.id == String(blocks[collectionView.tag].items[indexPath.row])}) {
        cell.gameName.text = found.name
        cell.gameImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity

        let processor = DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: CGSize(width: 225, height: 300))
        cell.gameImage.kf.setImage(
            with: URL(string: found.background_image ?? ""),
            options: [
                .processor(processor),
                .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                .transition(.fade(0.2)),
                .cacheOriginalImage
            ])
    }
    else {
        cell.gameName.text = ""
        cell.gameImage.image = nil
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return blocks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlockCell") as? BlockCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.blockName.text = blocks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.blockDescription.text = blocks[indexPath.row].description
    cell.setScrollPosition(x: offsets[indexPath] ?? 0)
    cell.gameCollectionCell.delegate = self
    cell.gameCollectionCell.dataSource = self
    cell.gameCollectionCell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.gameCollectionCell.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

I'm getting blocks and items in this controller. Now i want to detect a tap using LongTapGestureRecognizer on image in gamecollectionCell(UIcollectionViewCell inside BlockCell(TableviewCell). How can i do this? Or maybe any advice how to improve logic here?

Okay, i've added gesture recognizer like this in cellForItemAt :

```
cell.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(addGamePopUp)))
```

Then i need to animate uiimageview on long tap.

```
var selectedGameCell : GameCollectionCell?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedGameCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GameCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? GameCollectionCell 
}
```

And

```
@IBAction func addGamePopUp(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.selectedGameCell?.gameImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95,y: 0.95);
        }) { (Bool) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.selectedGameCell?.gameImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Did i miss something?

Comment: use `delegated` to `detect tab` from UICollectionview cell to table view

Answer (score 1):

You can use following delegate method of uicollectionview to detect tap on collection view cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    print("cell tapped")
}
```

For Adding Long Press Gesture Add Following Code in Cell For item at indexpath method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : GameCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! GameCollectionCell

        cell.backgroundColor = model[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item]

        let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addGamePopUp(_:)))
       cell.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

        return cell
 }


@IBAction func addGamePopUp(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        print("add game popup")
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.selectedGameCell?.gameImage?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95,y: 0.95);
            }) { (Bool) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.selectedGameCell?.gameImage?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 1);
                });
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i want to use longtapgesturerecognizer for example?

Comment: Add this two lines in your cellforitematindexpath method :         let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addGamePopUp(_:)))
       cell.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use longTapGestureRecognizer, just add one to the cell in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method of your collectionView, like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubjectCellId", for: indexPath) as? SubjectCell {
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(someMethod)))

        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've updated my questions, could you check it?

Comment: Your addGamePopup method isn't an IBAction - IBActions are triggered by interface builder (in your case, probably from your storyboard)

I'll leave another formatted reply so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use touchesBegan method inside tableview cell and from the touch location get the collection view cell object inside it.

NOTE: When you implement this method the didSelectRow method would not be called for the TableViewCell.

```
extension TableViewCell {
        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let point = touch.location(in: self)
                if let path = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
                    //Get cell of collection view from this index path
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get things working, I'd recommend changing your function from

`@IBAction func addGamePopUp(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {`

to

`@objc func addGamePopUp() {`

And when you're adding the longTapGestureRecognizer to your collectionViewCell, you'll have it trigger that method by changing the line to:

```
cell.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(addGamePopUp)))
```

Let me know if that works!

*(psst: also take out this if check in your addGamePopupMethod if you're going this route)*

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began){
```